# Drop-down Lists with Conditional Data

Tags: excel, input, form-control, vba

i have three ranges of cells (from another sheet in my workbook) that store the values that i want to appear on the drop-down (Form Control) list. i need the macro code to reset a cell range, or a named range to define the options in a drop-down list based on other cell value.
. 
i've tried the following code with no success so far:

> Sub DropDown11_Change()
>
> If Range("A1") = 1 Then
>   *(input range from sheet1 a1:a50)*
>
> ElseIf Range("A1") = 2 Then
>   *(input range from sheet2 a1:a50)*
>
> ElseIf Range("A1") = 3 Then
>     *(input range from sheet3 a1:a50)*
>
> End If
>   End Sub

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out, place either of these in a standard Module (e.g., Module1).

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    Dim ddFillRange As String

    If Sheet1.Range("A1") = 1 Then
        ddFillRange = "Sheet1!A1:A50"
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A1") = 2 Then
        ddFillRange = "Sheet2!A1:A50"
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A1") = 3 Then
        ddFillRange = "Sheet3!A1:A50"
    End If

    Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.ListFillRange = ddFillRange

End Sub
```

If you want to use named ranges, you can use:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    Dim ddFillRange As String

    If Sheet1.Range("A1") = 1 Then
        ddFillRange = Range("NamedRange1").Name
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A1") = 2 Then
        ddFillRange = Range("NamedRange2").Name
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A1") = 3 Then
        ddFillRange = Range("NamedRange3").Name
    End If

    Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.ListFillRange = ddFillRange

End Sub
```

Then, to have these fire upon cell A1 changing, you will need to place the following in Sheet1's module (when you right+click Sheet1 in the VBA Editor Window, select view code...see picture below):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then DropDown1_Change
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1 Code]

Comment: how to select the data range that i want to add to the combo box with named range?

Comment: @DhimasAFanji I updated my answer to include a named range approach.

Comment: This run, but when cell A1 changes the list does not change unless I have to click first,

Comment: @DhimasAFanji Sorry, didn't realize that was a requirement. Updating my answer shortly...

Comment: @DhimasAFanji cool, glad it helped, feel free to up-vote and select the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things utilizing named ranges. Here is an example that should help as well.

```
Sub DropDown11_Change()

Dim dropdown As String

If Range("A1") = 1 Then
    '(input range from sheet1 a1:a50)
    dropdown = "=Sheet1!R1C1:R50C1"
ElseIf Range("A1") = 2 Then
    '(input range from sheet2 a1:a50)
    dropdown = "=Sheet2!R1C1:R50C1"
ElseIf Range("A1") = 3 Then
    '(input range from sheet3 a1:a50)
    dropdown = "=Sheet3!R1C1:R50C1"

End If

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DynamicList", RefersToR1C1:=dropdown

End Sub
```

Comment: Just for clarification, when do you want this change to be triggered? When the dropdown changes or when Cell A1 changes?

Comment: thanks @Geoff, i want this change to be triggered when Cell A1 changes.

Comment: great, @jaysunice4301 is providing the answer below as I would respond.