# macros still running even if the cell/ range value changed

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select a range (B2) resulting from the dropdown referring from another range (source from F2: F5). I mean I do not need to change the values in the macro code if one day I had to change the data in the reference range (F2: F5). If the value in the range B2 is equal to the value of the text on one of the list range F2: F5 then the macro will run.

I want something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        If Range("B2").Value = Range("F3").Value Then
            Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("11:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("B2").Value = Range("F4").Value Then
            Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("11:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I re-write this logic in a way that is VBA friendly? Thanks for your help

Comment: use  named range in vba that will help run your even cells reference changes

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you better explain your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Target
   If .Address = "$B$2" Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False
      Select Case .Value
         Case Range("F3").Value
             Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
             Rows("11:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Case Range("F4").Value
             Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
             Rows("11:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End Select
     Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this also today .

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a `Worksheet_Change`... This activates on any changes to the sheet. (Put this code in the SHEET's CODE).  First it checks to make sure the cell is B2 then it checks to make sure B2's Value is found in your reference cells.  Then it does a Select Case for each possible option.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Select Case Range("B2").Value
    Case Range("F2").Value
        'Do Something
    Case Range("F3").Value
        'Do Something
    Case Range("F4").Value
        'Do Something
    Case Range("F5").Value
        'Do Something
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Intersect(Target.Address, ...` should be `Intersect(Target, ...`.  Your `Find` is redundant (the `Case Else` takes care of that case) and if the OP changes multiple cells in one go the Case statements will error.

Comment: Only if the OP changes multiple cells INCLUDING B2.  But since B2 is a dropdown, that isn't possible.

Comment: Copy/Paste of multiple cells into a range containing dropdowns _is_ possible.

Comment: Hence why I do the `Range.Find` before the `Select Case`.  Gets him out of the change sub faster.

Comment: If the copy puts a valid value in B2 along with other values elsewhere, then the Find will pass.

Comment: Edited... Happy now? :-P

Comment: I threw it in there to get out of the sub faster on erroneous changes elsewhere in the sheet.  But the `Intersect` already handles that so I'll go ahead and remove the find.

Comment: FWIW the code is actually faster without the Find, for both cases (B2 changed/not changed)

Comment: for different cases in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274030/drop-down-lists-with-conditional-data/27276193#27276193), how do I change this code with your method? `If Sheet19.Range("V9") = 1 Then
        ddFillRange = Range("Nam_1").Name`

Comment: That depends on your specific sheet.  I would need more details about your source for your dropdown, your cell which contains the dropdown, and then what you want it to do when the dropdown cell changes.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you not use the Select case structure:

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then

```
Select Case  Range("B2").Value 
    case Range("F3").Value 
       Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Rows("11:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    case Range("B2").Value = Range("F4").Value Then
       Rows("10:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Rows("11:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
..............
..............
..............

End Select
```

End If
End Sub

Comment: All this does it change his `If/ElseIf` to `Select Case`.  This doesn't solve the overall mechanic of the question (getting the code to run on a change to "B2")